# Are Spring Profiles and Spring Boot Profiles the same?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) is description about Spring Boot profiles and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-definition-profiles-java) is Spring profile description. At first glance if it is needed to use profiles thay easy can be used without Spring Boot. So does spring boot provide addituonal profile functionality to spring profiles?

Comment: It is about the same thing, but Spring boot brings additional features to profiles, like profile configuration properties (by using application-<profile>.properties), and allows you to configure the current profile with the spring.profiles.active property.

Comment: @g00glen00b why you didn't provide this as an answer? I think that you should :)

Answer (score 2):

They're both the same thing, namely profile configuration. However, Spring boot does bring some additional features to Spring profiles like:

- You can provide your application properties separately for each profile by using `application-<profile name>.properties` (or .yml) files. For example, if you create a file called **application-test.properties** and you run the application with this profile, Spring boot will load these configuration properties as well
- Spring boot also has a configuration property called `spring.profiles.active` which allows you to configure which profile(s) should be used for the Spring boot application.